# Bluetooth Programming in Raspberry Pi 4 using Bluez and dbus. Every thing is working good it just RPI is taking more than 90ms to receive 8 floats

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, dbus, raspberry-pi4, bluez

I'm working on a project in which Rpi will receive 8 floats from Arduino nano ble. Arduino is working as peripheral device and sending 8 floats through Bluetooth. Arduino code is as shown bellow.

```
#include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h>  // C:\Users\16312\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_LSM9DS1\src
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
String localName = "testPeripheral";

#define BLE_UUID_SENSOR_DATA_SERVICE              "2BEEF31A-B10D-271C-C9EA-35D865C1F48A"
#define BLE_UUID_MULTI_SENSOR_DATA                "4664E7A1-5A13-BFFF-4636-7D0A4B16496C"

#define NUMBER_OF_SENSORS 8

union multi_sensor_data
{
  struct __attribute__( ( packed ) )
  {
    float values[NUMBER_OF_SENSORS];
  };
  uint8_t bytes[ NUMBER_OF_SENSORS * sizeof( float ) ];
};

union multi_sensor_data multiSensorData;

BLEService sensorDataService( BLE_UUID_SENSOR_DATA_SERVICE );
BLECharacteristic multiSensorDataCharacteristic( BLE_UUID_MULTI_SENSOR_DATA, BLERead | BLENotify, sizeof multiSensorData.bytes );

static long previousMillis = 0;
#define UPDATE_INTERVALL 50

float iter;
float dt;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //while (!Serial);

  initBLE();

  if (!IMU.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize IMU!");
    while (1);
  }
  iter = 0;
}


void serial_print_xyz(float x, float y, float z) {
  int num_digits = 6;
  Serial.print(x, num_digits);  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print(y, num_digits);  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print(z, num_digits);  Serial.print('\t');
}

void serial_print_1(float val) {
  int num_digits = 6;
  Serial.print(val, num_digits);  Serial.print('\t');
}

void serial_print_1(int val) {
  Serial.print(val);  Serial.print('\t');
}

void serial_print_endln() {
  Serial.print("end");   Serial.println();
}



void loop() {
  //comment below line to remove serial print of master address

  dt = millis()-previousMillis;
  float acc_x, acc_y, acc_z;
  float mag_x, mag_y, mag_z;
  // Magnetic field seems to read at a slower rate than acceleration?
  if (IMU.accelerationAvailable() && IMU.magneticFieldAvailable()) {
    if ( millis() - previousMillis > UPDATE_INTERVALL )
    {
      previousMillis =  millis();
      // Read measurements
      IMU.readAcceleration(acc_x, acc_y, acc_z);
      IMU.readMagneticField(mag_x, mag_y, mag_z);
      iter++;
      // Export measurements
      checkCentralConnect();  //check if slave is connected to Master
      
      updateIMU(acc_x, acc_y, acc_z, mag_x, mag_y, mag_z);

      
      Serial.print("start\t");
      serial_print_1(iter);
      serial_print_1(dt);
      serial_print_xyz(acc_x, acc_y, acc_z);
      serial_print_xyz(mag_x, mag_y, mag_z);
      serial_print_endln();
    }
  }

}

void initBLE()
{
  // begin initialization
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");
  }

  // set advertised local name and service UUID:
  BLE.setDeviceName( "Arduino Nano 33 BLE" );
  BLE.setLocalName( "Arduino Nano 33 BLE" );
  BLE.setAdvertisedService( sensorDataService );

  // BLE add characteristics
  sensorDataService.addCharacteristic( multiSensorDataCharacteristic );

  // add service
  BLE.addService( sensorDataService );

  // set the initial value for the characeristic:
  multiSensorDataCharacteristic.writeValue( multiSensorData.bytes, sizeof multiSensorData.bytes );

  // start advertising
  BLE.advertise();

  String address = BLE.address();
  Serial.print("Local mac address is: ");
  Serial.println(address);
  Serial.println("LocalName: Arduino Nano 33 BLE");
}

void checkCentralConnect()
{
  // listen for BLE centrals to connect:
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();

  // if a central is connected to peripheral print mac address
  if (central) {
    //Serial.print("Connected to central: ");
    // print the central's MAC address:
    //Serial.print(central.address());
  }
}

void updateIMU(float accX, float accY, float accZ, float magX, float magY, float magZ)
{

  multiSensorData.values[0]  = accX;
  multiSensorData.values[1]  = accY;
  multiSensorData.values[2]  = accZ;

  multiSensorData.values[3]  = magX;
  multiSensorData.values[4]  = magY;
  multiSensorData.values[5]  = magZ;
  multiSensorData.values[6]  = dt;
  multiSensorData.values[7]  = iter;

  multiSensorDataCharacteristic.writeValue( multiSensorData.bytes, sizeof multiSensorData.bytes );
}
```

In this code you can see the Arduino is sending data on serial port also and out of this 8 floats 2 floats are iteration and execution time of one loop, so by examine serial output from Arduino i can tell how much time Arduino is taking to send data over Bluetooth. And what i found is Arduino is taking approx 50ms for a loop but in this 50 ms, IMU sensors are taking 48 to 49ms in each loop(if i remove code that is used to get values from IMU then execution time for a loop is 1ms only). Arduino is taking only 1ms to send data through Bluetooth. But on other hand the RPI is taking more than 90ms to receive this 8 floats from Arduino. I'm using BlueZ stack for Bluetooth communication in Linux and Python Dbus module to communicate with BlueZ using python. I attached Bluetooth scanner and data reader code bellow. When class is initializes it scans for devices and if found Arduino it will connect with it. after initialization is done code starts reading characteristics values. I'm using while loop to read values continuously but I'm not able to understand why RPI is taking more than 90ms just to read 8 float values(Check main loop code in the bottom part of python code). I'm very new to python and Dbus programming please help me figure out how can i increase the Bluetooth data transfer speed in RPI. If there is another method and I'm using wrong or old method please just provide a link to the documentation through which i can understand what is the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import GLib
import bluetooth_utils
import bluetooth_constants
import dbus
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import sys
#import pydbus
import struct
from allDefData import defData

sys.path.insert(0, '.')

adapter_interface = None
mainloop = None
timer_id = None

devices = {}

class bleScan():

    def __init__(self, defD):
        # dbus initialisation steps
        self.defD = defD
        self.adapter_path = bluetooth_constants.BLUEZ_NAMESPACE + bluetooth_constants.ADAPTER_NAME
        self.ArdunoBleD = lambda: None
        dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        self.get_through_list_connected_devices()

        print(hasattr(self.ArdunoBleD, 'Name'))
        while(not hasattr(self.ArdunoBleD, 'Name')):
            print("Scanning")
            self.discover_devices(self.bus, 2000)
            if hasattr(self.ArdunoBleD, 'Name') and defD.ArdBleName in self.ArdunoBleD.Name:

                print("Scanning Stoped")
                break
            else:
                print("Not found Rescanning")
        char_proxy = self.bus.get_object(bluetooth_constants.BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, '/org/bluez/hci0/dev_1B_4E_C8_D6_CC_06/service000a/char000b')
        self.char_interface = dbus.Interface(char_proxy, bluetooth_constants.GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_INTERFACE)


    def Som(self, interfaces, path):

        if bluetooth_constants.GATT_SERVICE_INTERFACE in interfaces:
            properties = interfaces[bluetooth_constants.GATT_SERVICE_INTERFACE]
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------")
            print("SVC path :", path)
            if 'UUID' in properties:
                uuid = properties['UUID']
            if uuid == bluetooth_constants.TEMPERATURE_SVC_UUID:
                found_ts = True
                ts_path = path
            print("SVC UUID : ", bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(uuid))
            print("SVC name : ", bluetooth_utils.get_name_from_uuid(uuid))
            return
        if bluetooth_constants.GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_INTERFACE in interfaces:
            properties = interfaces[bluetooth_constants.GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_INTERFACE]
            print(" CHR path :", path)
            if 'UUID' in properties:
                uuid = properties['UUID']
            if uuid == bluetooth_constants.TEMPERATURE_CHR_UUID:
                found_tc = True
            tc_path = path
            print(" CHR UUID : ", bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(uuid))
            print(" CHR name : ", bluetooth_utils.get_name_from_uuid(uuid))
            flags = ""
            for flag in properties['Flags']:
                flags = flags + flag + ","
            print(" CHR flags : ", flags)
            return
        if bluetooth_constants.GATT_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE in interfaces:
            properties =interfaces[bluetooth_constants.GATT_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE]
            print(" DSC path :", path)
            if 'UUID' in properties:
                uuid = properties['UUID']
            print(" DSC UUID : ", bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(uuid))
            print(" DSC name : ", bluetooth_utils.get_name_from_uuid(uuid))
            return

    def get_through_list_connected_devices(self):
        bus = self.bus
        proxy = bus.get_object(bluetooth_constants.BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, '/')
        interface = dbus.Interface(proxy, bluetooth_constants.DBUS_OM_IFACE)
        mngd_objs = interface.GetManagedObjects()
        for path, interfaces in mngd_objs.items():
            print(path)

            for ainterface in interfaces:
                print(ainterface)
                if ainterface == bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE:
                    device_properties = interfaces[bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE]
                    #if path not in devices:
                    devices[path] = device_properties
                    dev = devices[path]
                    try:
                        adr_name_Conn_inDev = ('Address' and 'Name' and 'Connected' in dev)
                        arduinoName_isCorrect = self.defD.ArdBleName in bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Name'])
                        isConnected = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(device_properties['Connected'])

                    except:
                        adr_name_Conn_inDev = False
                        arduinoName_isCorrect = False
                        isConnected = False

                    if adr_name_Conn_inDev and arduinoName_isCorrect and isConnected:
                        self.ArdunoBleD.Name = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Name'])
                        self.ArdunoBleD.Address = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Address'])
                        #self.ArdunoBleD.RSSI = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['RSSI'])
                        self.ArdunoBleD.Path = path
                        self.Som(interfaces , path)
                        print("Found: Arduino Nano Ble in Connected Dev")
                    elif adr_name_Conn_inDev and arduinoName_isCorrect and not isConnected:
                        print("Not found in connected Devices")
                        print("Connecting...")
                        self.connect(path)
                        if self.isConnected(path):
                            self.ArdunoBleD.Name = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Name'])
                            self.ArdunoBleD.Address = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Address'])
                            # self.ArdunoBleD.RSSI = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['RSSI'])
                            self.ArdunoBleD.Path = path
                            self.Som(interfaces, path)



                    # if 'Address' in dev:
                    #     print("EXI bdaddr: ", bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(device_properties['Address']))
                    # if 'Name' in device_properties:
                    #     print("Name: ", bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(device_properties['Name']))
                    # if 'Connected' in device_properties:
                    #     print("Con: ", bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(device_properties['Connected']))





    def isConnected(self, device_path):
        bus = self.bus
        proxy = bus.get_object(bluetooth_constants.BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, device_path)
        interface = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        print("----------------")
        return interface.Get(bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE, 'Connected')


    def connect(self, device_path):
        bus = self.bus

        device_proxy = bus.get_object(bluetooth_constants.BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, device_path)
        device_interface = dbus.Interface(device_proxy, bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE)
        #p_interface = dbus.Interface(device_proxy, bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE)
        try:
            device_interface.Connect()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to connect")
            print(e.get_dbus_name())
            print(e.get_dbus_message())
            if ("UnknownObject" in e.get_dbus_name()):
                print("Try scanning first to resolve this problem")
                return bluetooth_constants.RESULT_EXCEPTION
        else:
            print("Connected OK")
            return bluetooth_constants.RESULT_OK

    def interfaces_added(self, path, interfaces):
        # interfaces is an array of dictionary entries
        if not bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE in interfaces:
            return

        device_properties = interfaces[bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE]
        print(path)
        if path not in devices:
            print("NEW path :", path)
            devices[path] = device_properties
            dev = devices[path]

            if ('Address' and 'Name' and 'RSSI' in dev) and self.defD.ArdBleName in bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(
                    dev['Name']):

                self.connect(path)
                if self.isConnected(path):
                    self.ArdunoBleD.Name = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Name'])
                    self.ArdunoBleD.Address = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Address'])
                    self.ArdunoBleD.RSSI = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['RSSI'])
                    self.ArdunoBleD.Path = path
                    self.Som(interfaces, path)
                # self.ArdunoBleD.Name = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Name'])
                # self.ArdunoBleD.Address = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Address'])
                # self.ArdunoBleD.RSSI = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['RSSI'])
                # self.ArdunoBleD.Path = path
                print("Found: Arduino Nano Ble")

                self.discovery_timeout()
        print("------------------------------")

    def interfaces_removed(self, path, interfaces):

        # interfaces is an array of dictionary strings in this signal
        if not bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE in interfaces:
            return
        if path in devices:
            dev = devices[path]
        if 'Address' in dev:
            print("DEL bdaddr: ",
              bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(dev['Address']))
        else:
            print("DEL path : ", path)
        print("Rem",path)
        del devices[path]

    def discovery_timeout(self):
        global adapter_interface

        global mainloop
        global timer_id
        GLib.source_remove(timer_id)
        mainloop.quit()
        adapter_interface.StopDiscovery()
        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        bus.remove_signal_receiver(self.interfaces_added, "InterfacesAdded")
        bus.remove_signal_receiver(self.interfaces_removed, "InterfacesRemoved")
        return True

    def read_temperature(self):


        char_interface = self.char_interface
        try:
            self.value = char_interface.ReadValue({})
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to read temperature")
            print(e.get_dbus_name())
            print(e.get_dbus_message())
            return bluetooth_constants.RESULT_EXCEPTION
        # else:
        #     self.temperature = bluetooth_utils.dbus_to_python(self.value[0])
        #     #print("Temperature=" + str(self.temperature ) + "C")
        #     return bluetooth_constants.RESULT_OK


    def discover_devices(self, bus, timeout):
        global adapter_interface
        global mainloop
        global timer_id


        # acquire an adapter proxy object and its Adapter1 interface so we can
        # call its methods
        adapter_object = bus.get_object(bluetooth_constants.BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, self.adapter_path)
        adapter_interface = dbus.Interface(adapter_object, bluetooth_constants.ADAPTER_INTERFACE)
        # register signal handler functions so we can asynchronously report
        # discovered devices
        # InterfacesAdded signal is emitted by BlueZ when an advertising packet
        # from a device it doesn't
        # already know about is received
        bus.add_signal_receiver(self.interfaces_added, dbus_interface=bluetooth_constants.DBUS_OM_IFACE,
                                signal_name="InterfacesAdded")
        bus.add_signal_receiver(self.interfaces_removed,
                                dbus_interface=bluetooth_constants.DBUS_OM_IFACE,
                                signal_name="InterfacesRemoved")

        mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
        timer_id = GLib.timeout_add(timeout, self.discovery_timeout)
        adapter_interface.StartDiscovery(byte_arrays=True)
        mainloop.run()
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':

    defD = defData()
    Dev = bleScan(defD)

    while(True):
        if hasattr(Dev.ArdunoBleD, 'Name') and Dev.isConnected(Dev.ArdunoBleD.Path):
            time1 = time.time()
            Dev.read_temperature()
            print("hmm", Dev.value)
            s = struct.unpack('8f', bytearray(Dev.value))
            print(s)
            dt2 = time.time() - time1
            print(dt2)
        else:
            print("Er")
```

Output of Arduino is as Bellow

```
start   309.000000  52.000000   0.033325    0.993530    -0.032715   0.329590    -1.257324   -1.013184   end
start   310.000000  50.000000   0.033569    0.993408    -0.034668   0.305176    -1.354980   -2.331543   end
```

8 Numbers between start and end are the 8 floats which is Arduino is sending over Bluetooth and first float is iteration and second is the execution time of one loop in ms.

Output of Python code is as shown bellow.

```
hmm dbus.Array([dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(234), dbus.Byte(60), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(56), dbus.Byte(126), dbus.Byte(63), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(128), dbus.Byte(101), dbus.Byte(189), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(128), dbus.Byte(59), dbus.Byte(62), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(32), dbus.Byte(25), dbus.Byte(191), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(224), dbus.Byte(43), dbus.Byte(191), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(72), dbus.Byte(66), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(104), dbus.Byte(178), dbus.Byte(69)], signature=dbus.Signature('y'))
(0.028564453125, 0.9930419921875, -0.0560302734375, 0.18310546875, -0.59814453125, -0.67138671875, 50.0, 5709.0)
0.09242081642150879
----------------


hmm dbus.Array([dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(231), dbus.Byte(60), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(144), dbus.Byte(126), dbus.Byte(63), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(128), dbus.Byte(99), dbus.Byte(189), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(97), dbus.Byte(190), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(128), dbus.Byte(9), dbus.Byte(191), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(160), dbus.Byte(215), dbus.Byte(191), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(68), dbus.Byte(66), dbus.Byte(0), dbus.Byte(120), dbus.Byte(178), dbus.Byte(69)], signature=dbus.Signature('y'))
(0.0281982421875, 0.994384765625, -0.0555419921875, -0.2197265625, -0.537109375, -1.6845703125, 49.0, 5711.0)
0.092437744140625
----------------
```

Answer (score 1):

To speed things up use Indications or Notifications on the RPi end. These are a way for a GATT Client to subscribe to data provided by a GATT Server. A Notification is an unacknowledged message or update while an Indication is an acknowledged message or update. As you are going to be updating so frequently it would seem sensible to go with notifications.
This would be done in the MainLoop rather than a While loop. This is covered in BlueZ GATT API https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt#n181

This should be enough to get you the speed-up you are looking for. If you still need more then there is AcquireNotify.

BlueZ D-Bus goes through various OS layers when doing notifications which is known to slow the rate at which data can be updated. To overcome this, in later versions, BlueZ introduced AcquireNotify which opens a socket to bypass some of the layers to speed things up.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, it working perfectly now as i wanted. Actualy i thought notifications are for very low speed transmission but it allways opposite to what i think but thanks a lot for this. I just needed a direction and you provided that. I have one more issue if you can help that would be great.

Comment: When i run code for first time it finds device and connect sucessfully and in letter on first it will check in managed devices and check if it connected or not. now it is ok if Arduino is already connected but what if some how arduino bluetooth is stopped. in this case Arduino will still available in manged devices but how do i know it is available in near by or not, if it is in nearby devices then i can connect to it but if Arduino bluetooth service is stopped and if i try to connect then it will give error.

Comment: And if I call discover divices then Arduino will not available in new devices as it is already available in managed devices so is there any way to remove a perticular device path if that bluetooth is turned off.

Comment: This sounds like you need to create a new question so that there is space for people to answer it.

Comment: @ukBaz Do you happen to have any example of using AcquireNotify from a Python application?

Comment: Yeah, sure have. Where's your question @JasonWright ?

Comment: @ukBaz Just posted one here, any advice you could give would be greatly appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499147/per-connection-notifications-using-bluez-peripheral