# Per-connection notifications using BlueZ peripheral

Tags: bluez

I want to use BlueZ as a peripheral / GATT server, and have multiple central devices connect and subscribe to a particular characteristic. Then, I want to send a notification to only 1 of the connected centrals via a Python application. The subscription behavior is in a piece of code I can't control, so having only 1 central be subscribed is not an option. I also need the connection to stay active, so disconnecting from the other devices is also not an option.

I have the GATT server working, notifying all connected centrals via the `PropertiesChanged` DBus method, by following the [example-gatt-server](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server) method. The DBus API does not provide a way to deliver a notification to a particular connection handle or connected device, so instead I think my application needs to interact with a BlueZ file descriptor directly. I found that adding the `NotifyAcquired` property could trigger a call to an implementation of `AcquireNotify`:

```
class Characteristic(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1 interface implementation
    """
    def __init__(self, bus, index, uuid, flags, service):
        self.path = service.path + '/char' + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.service = service
        self.flags = flags
        self.descriptors = []
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)

    def get_properties(self):
        return {
                GATT_CHRC_IFACE: {
                        'Service': self.service.get_path(),
                        'UUID': self.uuid,
                        'Flags': self.flags,
                        'Descriptors': dbus.Array(
                                self.get_descriptor_paths(),
                                signature='o'),
                        'NotifyAcquired': False
                }
        }

    ...

    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, in_signature='a{sv}', out_signature='hq')
    def AcquireNotify(self, options):
        print('Default AcquireNotify called, returning error')
        raise NotSupportedException()
```

This leaves me with two questions:

1. How do I generate the fd object that `AcquireNotify` is expected to return?
2. How can I use the fd object to deliver a notification to a particular connected device?

Comment: The major advantage of AcquireNotify is that it uses an file descriptors for the data rather than going through D-Bus so I don't think it will give you want you want. The centrals should only get updates if they have subscribed to get updates when the value of the peripheral changes. If all the centrals have subscribed then they will all get updates, else how does your peripheral know which to update?

Comment: What I want is to exclude some centrals from receiving notifications. For example, my peripheral knows it's connected to centrals A and B, and even though both A and B have subscribed to the characteristic, I want to send my notifications to only A. (The peripheral would know whether to choose A or B based on some other application logic.)
While this is an unconventional use case, it's possible in other stacks e.g. in Zephyr: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/reference/bluetooth/gatt.html#c.bt_gatt_notify (conn handle argument)
If not via file descriptor is there any other way?

Comment: Not possible with Bluez